# If file with name.jpg exists do A else do B

Tags: php, file, variables, if-statement

I need to develop a little PHP script that I can run from a cron job which in pseudo code does the following:

```
//THIS IS PSEUDO CODE
If(file exists with name 'day.jpg')
    rename it to 'fixtures.jpg'
else
    copy 'master.jpg' to 'fixtures.jpg'
```

Where `day.jpg` should be the current day of the month.

I started to replace the pseudo code with the stuff I'm pretty sure how to do:

```
<?php

    if(FILE EXISTS WITH NAME DAY.JPG) {
        rename ("DAY.JPG", "fixtures.jpg");
    } else {
        copy ("master.jpg", "fixtures.jpg");
    }

?>
```

Clearly there are still a few things missing. Like I need to get the filename with the current day of the month and I need to check if the file exists or not.

I guess I need to do something like this `$filename='date('j');'.jpg` to get the filename, but it isn't really working so I kinda need a bit help there. Also I don't really know how to check if a file exists or not?

Comment: what is the problem/question?

Comment: just piecing it all together really... gonna post an update now

Comment: Can I ask why you need to rename the file and not apply the logic to the code responsible for your output? eg `on the 2nd, echo 2.jpg`

Comment: ` if($filename = date('j') . '.jpg';) {` this is wrong you should change it to `if (date('j') . '.jpg' == $filename ) {`

Comment: @Robert I think update 2 posted is better

Comment: @HenryAspden Update 2 looks like it should work. Does it? Or where are you still stuck?

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123 yea I fell asleep last night haha but yea works like a dream... I even tweaked it this morning to delete the day befores file... e.g on the 9th of the month delete 8.jpg... I'll post UPDATE 3 for others to look at. Guess it might help someone in the future

Comment: @HenryAspden Please don't post the working code inside the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = __DIR__; // define path here
$fileName = sprintf("%s%d.jpg", $path, date("j"));
$fixtures = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "fixtures.jpg";
$master   = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "master.jpg";

file_exists($fileName) ? rename($fileName, $fixtures) : copy($master, $fixtures);
```

Basicly you need script like above but you need to work on your path. Your code above had syntax problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have a basic syntax problem, it should be:

```
$filename = date('j') . '.jpg';
```

You don't put function calls inside quotes, you need quotes around the literal string '.jpg', and you need to use `.` to concatenate them.

I recommend you read the chapter on Strings in a PHP tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Barmar thats a big help... quick one tho, when do I use == vs just =?

Comment: @HenryAspden If you needed that, you **really** need to read a PHP tutorial from beginning to front, not just the strings chapter.

Comment: I've posted an update to my code above, will somebody please take a quick look at it now. Any links to explain where and why my syntax etc is wrong would be really helpful :) As you can see I'm new to PHP. Don't really know where or how to start teaching myself the language other than project by project

Comment: You shouldn't put the variable assignment inside `if()`. If you want to know if the file exists, use `if(file_exists($filename))`

Comment: @Barmar... PHP tutorial you say?

Comment: Yes, you clearly need to learn how to program in PHP, you don't know some of the simplest concepts.

Comment: I appreciate it must be frustating to read my novice codes haha... I am trying to learn hence why I didn't just code dump and expect the answer... this time

Comment: You can't learn to program by trial and error like this, you need to get a good textbook or tutorial. Don't ask me for a recommendation, I don't know.

Comment: @Barmar thanks anyway buddy... might look at some apps I can do on my phone and see if there are any good'uns... What do you think to UPDATE 2 if you don't mind me bombarding you?

Comment: works like a dream guys... time to start at the basics after this one